# can i have AjaxSetup in multiple .js. files?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

js and createData.js files where all stuff is included.

i need to include

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
            //somestuff
        }
    }
});
```

in my js files for session controll.

Is it normal to have multiple ajaxsetups in different js files?

Comment: No, this isn't normal. This is a global change so it will effect the entire system. That's unless your using multiple versions of jquery and `noConflict`.

Comment: The $.ajaxSetup() function set default values for all future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended.
For details on the settings available for $.ajaxSetup(), see [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),like:

    jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )

Comment: so how i can catch session timeouts?? for ajax calls?